# Como consumir uma mensagem de uma fila MQ remota utilisando MDB em servidores JBoss

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss, ejb, jms

Tenho uma classe EJB que escreve uma mensagem em uma fila JMS e gostaria de consumir esta mensagem a partir de um MessageDrivenBean (MDB) instalado em outro servidor.

A minha classe escreve na fila JMS com sucesso, porém o servidor não consome a mensagem. Nenhum erro é apresentado, a mensagem fica na fila sem ser consumida.

O usuário *guest* foi criado. Os testes estão sendo realizados em duas instâncias do JBoss na minha máquina local rodando em portas diferentes.

Quando o MDB está no mesmo EAR do EJB cliente (local), funciona.

Meu ambiente é JBoss EAP 7.1 com Java 8.

#### Classe EJB que escreve na fila:

```
@Stateless
public class ManagerService {

    public void writeQueue() throws NamingException {

        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)context.lookup("java:/jms/birt_connectionFactory");
        Queue queue = (Queue)context.lookup("java:/jms/birt_queue");

        try(JMSContext jmsContext = factory.createContext("guest", "guest")) {

            JMSProducer producerPDF = jmsContext.createProducer();

            String message = "Hello distant world!";
            producerPDF.send(queue, message);
            System.out.println("PDF sender: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Classe MDB que recebe a mensagem:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:/jms/birt_queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "java:/jms/birt_connectionFactory"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "guest"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "guest"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "7"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionParameters", propertyValue = "host=127.0.0.1;port=8180")
})
public class PDFQueueReceiver implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)message;

        try {      
            System.out.println("Remote PDF receiver: " + textMessage.getText());
        }
        catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### standalone.xml do servidor JBoss cliente

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>

        <jms-queue name="birt_queue" entries="java:/jms/birt_queue" durable="false"/>

        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>

        <connection-factory name="birt_connectionFactory" entries="java:/jms/birt_connectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: já tentou trocar o connectionParameters para o ip do servidor ao invés de 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @André, estou fazendo os testes em duas instâncias do JBoss na minha máquina local rodando em portas diferentes, por isso coloquei 127.0.0.1. De qualquer forma, acabei de colocar o IP real da máquina para testar e não funcionou.

Comment: Vi que você não criou um conector remoto, vai precisar, segue um link de exemplo http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/connecting-to-an-external-wildfly-jms-server

Comment: @André, obrigado pela indicação, ela me ajudou como ponto inicial para chegar à uma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue a resolução do problema em questão.

<sub>**Atenção:** esta solução não leva em consideração fatores importantes para um projeto em produção, como segurança, melhor arquitetura, balanceamento, etc.</sub>

#### Primeira etapa: configuração do servidor(A) que irá gerar as mensagens em sua fila local:

No arquivo `standalone.xml` do servidor que irá produzir as mensagens em sua fila local deve-se criar:

- Um `socket-binding` para disponibilizar uma porta de entrada para o consumidor remoto das mensagens.
- Um `remote-acceptor`do sistema de filas ligado ao `socket-binding` criado para que a fila seja publicada.
- Um `jms-queue`(fila local) que receberá as mensagens. **Importante:** para ser pública, o nome da fila deve iniciar com `java:jboss/exported/`

**standalone.xml** do servidor contendo a fila:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        ...
        <remote-acceptor name="birt-messaging-acceptor" socket-binding="birt-messaging"/>
        ...
        <jms-queue name="birt_queue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/birt_queue" durable="false"/>
        ...
        </server>
</subsystem>
...
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
    ...
    <socket-binding name="birt-messaging" port="4751"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

#### Segunda etapa: configuração do servidor(B) que irá consumir as mensagens de forma remota através de um `MessageDrivenBean`:

No arquivo `standalone.xml` do servidor que irá consumir as mensagens da fila remota deve-se criar:

- Um `outbound-socket-binding` que especifica o endereço do servidor remoto.
- Um `remote-connector` do sistema de filas ligado ao `outbound-socket-binding`.
- Um `connection-factory` ligado ao `remote-connector`, o qual será utilizado pelo `MessageDrivenBean`.
- Um `jms-queue` com o mesmo nome da fila remota, que servirá como fachada.

**standalone.xml** do servidor contendo o `MessageDrivenBean` que irá consumir a fila remota:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        ...
        <remote-connector name="birt-connector" socket-binding="birt-messaging"/>
        ...
        <jms-queue name="birt_queue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/birt_queue" durable="false"/>
        ...
        <connection-factory name="BirtConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/BirtConnectionFactory" connectors="birt-connector"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
...
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
    ...
    <outbound-socket-binding name="birt-messaging">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="4751"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

#### Terceira etapa: criar as classes que irão escrever na fila e consumir as mensagens da fila.

**Classe EJB instalada no Servidor(A) que escreve mensagens na fila:**

```
@Stateless
public class ManagerService {

    @Inject
    private JMSContext jmsContext;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/birt_queue")
    private Queue queue;

    public void writeQueue() {

        JMSProducer producerPDF = jmsContext.createProducer();
        String message = "Hello distant world!";
        producerPDF.send(queue, message);
        System.out.println("PDF sender: " + message);
    }
}
```

**Classe MDB instalada no servidor(B) que consome as mensagens da fila remota:**

```
@MessageDriven(name = "PDFQueueReceiver", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/queue/birt_queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/BirtConnectionFactory"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "guest"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password",propertyValue = "guest")
})
public class PDFQueueReceiver implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)message;
        try {
            System.out.println("Remote PDF receiver: " + textMessage.getText());
        }
        catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```